# DataTables row details using parent columns for child row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

Is it possible to have the row details in DataTables show data below but aligned with the parent columns? I notice that when I use row details with `row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();` this will create another `<tr>` but then it will also add a `<td colspan>` which I do not want to happen.

This is the row created when using `row.child()`:

```
<tr><td colspan="17"><tr><td></td><td></td><td>January 12, 2016</td><td>Clientname</td><td>Projectname</td><td>Taskname</td></tr></td></tr>
```

I also attached a picture below to show that I would like January 12, 2016 to line up with the parent Date column, the Clientname lined up with parent Client column and so on....

[image]

Anyone know a way to do this?

Here is my current code for row details:

```
        if (row.child.isShown()) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        } else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }

function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
        return  '<tr>'+
                            '<td></td>'+
                            '<td></td>'+
                            '<td>January 12, 2016</td>'+
                            '<td>Clientname</td>'+
                            '<td>Projectname</td>'+
                            '<td>Taskname</td>'+
                        '</tr>';
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach to this was to:

1. Create a temporary table row:

   `tmpRow = table.row.add(data).draw().node();`
2. Clone the temporary row's node:

   `childNode = $(tmpRow).clone(true);`
3. Show child using the cloned node:

   `row.child(childNode).show();`
4. Remove the temporary table row:

   `table.row(tmpRow).remove().draw();`

Pros:

- Uses table column definitions
- No extra HTML code (i.e. `format()`)
- Minimal code
- Clean, no hacks

Cons:

- Table has to redraw the temporary node in order to get a `domNode` to pass to the child
- User may experience a "flash" of seeing the temporary row for a second (and pagination counts)

It's clean and it works and you can mitigate the caveats with some CSS.

Here is the full solution with documentation walk-through:

```
/**
 * @description
 * Expands the parent row and reveals the child row.
 * In this example, data is simply copied from the parent row 
 * for illustration purposes, but in reality can be retrieved 
 * from a promise or nested object key.
 *
 * @param {event} row onclick event
 * @return {void}
 */
expandRow = function (e) {
    const data = e.data, // customize or load data from AJAX
        table = $('#myDatatable').DataTable(),
        tr = $(e.target).closest('tr'),
        row = table.row(tr);

    /**
     * @description
     * Hide the parent row
     */
    if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
        $(tr).removeClass('shown');
        row.child.hide();
    }
    /**
     * @description
     * Show the parent row
     */
    else {
        /**
         * @description
         * Draw a new row `tmpRow` in the table
         * and clone its dom node
         */
        const tmpRow = table.row.add(data).draw().node(),
            childNode = $(tmpRow).clone(true);

        /**
         * @description
         * Append the child to the parent row
         */
        row.child(childNode).show();
        $(tr).addClass('shown');

        /**
         * @description
         * Remove the `tmpRow` from the table
         */
        table.row(tmpRow).remove().draw();
    }

};
```

Comment: best solutions available here https://stackoverflow.com/a/31097029/2106820

Comment: @ArfanMirza none of those solutions solve OP's question in that thread, he needs all visible columns in the child row with the same responsiveness of the table so the data can be easily viewed

Comment: @ArfanMirza this solution is the best one given so far in both threads. The other answers are just rewording the official documentation. The docs say that child rows have no relationship to the parent so the problem we were having is that we could not create child rows that matched columns to the parent row, this includes the responsiveness of the table. This is important for visualizing the data if someone resizes their window. In this solution he clones the above row and appends it as a child with the new data, this solves every issue and you can even hide columns and keep the styling.

Answer (score 0):

Though I'm not sure how to make the columns line up the DataTables website does have an example of this. They make the child row become several rows with the column headers as the first column. The example is [here](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/row_details.html). Since it looks like there are only a few column in your parent row this might work for you. The DataTables example only shows 3 rows as the children, but it would be easily modified to have all 4 columns that you show in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem some time ago but after couple of years I see there is still no correct answer here.

Just create table row with the same amount of table cells as the parent row and return as an "array" - see below:

```
function format(d) {
    var childRow = '<tr>' +
            '<td></td>' +
            '<td></td>' +
            '<td>January 12, 2016</td>' +
            '<td>Clientname</td>' +
            '<td>Projectname</td>' +
            '<td>Taskname</td>' +
            '</tr>';
    return $(childRow).toArray();
}
```